# Set up instance of Drupal website on fresh Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, drupal, documentroot, drupal7

I am a brand new to Drupal...and web programming, for that matter. I have set up an Ubuntu 12.10 server, installed Apache, and installed Drupal 7.24 (all through bash...I am working from the server ssh). I now want to take a Drupal repository from GitHub and load an identical instance of this website on my server...yes, I have the permission of the site's administrator. My server currently uses /var/www/ as the DocumentRoot...which points to index.html. However, in my limited Drupal knowledge I know that I should be pointing the DocumentRoot at my GitHub repository's index.php file.

Here's my question(s): 1) How do I get my server to load up the index.php file instead of index.html? 2) Is there anything special I need to be doing after I point my DocumentRoot at the index.php file...in other words, will the entire website just magically "show up" in my browser once the server looks at the index.php file?

Sorry, for any ambiguity. I can clarify, if necessary. Thanks.

Comment: Apache looks for filenames in order. If you just delete index.html, index.php should load first (prodived libapache2-mod-php5 is installed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DocumentRoot specifies the folder where your site is held. Which file Apache looks for once it "Gets there" is defined by the DirectoryIndex directive. That said, I doubt this is actually what you want to do!

It sounds like you need to install php support for Apache, as Ubuntu normally takes care of adding index.php to your Apache config.

```
sudo apt-get install php5
# You MAY also need to:
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
# You WILL have to:
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```